# Sample orientation in the class, clustered by k-means in Python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, k-means

I've got some clustered classes, and a sample with a prediction. Now, i want to know the "orientation" of the sample, which varies from 0 to 1, where 0 - right in the class center, 1 - right on the class border(radius). I guess, it's going to be

`orientation=dist_from_center/class_radius`

So, I'm struggled to find class radius. The first idea is to take the distance from a center to the most distant sample, but iwould like to use smth more 'academic' and less custom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you're defining the orientation to us seems like you've got the right idea. If you use the farthest distance from the center as the denominator, then you'll get 0 as your minimum (cluster center) and 1 as your maximum (the farthest distance) and a linear distance in-between.

Comment: So, You think, i should use fathest distance? Are there an special methods like `km.radius_(class)`?

Comment: If you want your orientation to behave like that, then no. Your idea is correct